# Ruby on Rails - PendingMigrationError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

I'm just starting on an existing project built using RoR, which is totally new to me.

With the aim of getting a little ahead, I tried to boot up the project using `rails s`, but I'm getting the following error in the browser:

```
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError 

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

When I run this command I get the following in the console, but the browser just refreshes back to the same error?

```
ansi: 'gem install win32console' to use color on Windows
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop

ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError (

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

        bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

):

activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:572:in `check_pending!'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:548:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
bugsnag (5.1.0) lib/bugsnag/rack.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:131:in `call_app'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
request_store (1.4.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
rack-cors (0.4.0) lib/rack/cors.rb:80:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

If I run the `rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development` command, I get the following, which I don't recognise:

```
ansi: 'gem install win32console' to use color on Windows
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
== 20161205141923 AddLastSeenAtToUsers: migrating =============================
-- add_column(:users, :last_seen_at, :datetime)
   -> 0.0020s
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.deleted_at does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS ...
                                            ^
: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL
C:/projectName/db/migrate/20161205141923_add_last_seen_at_to_users.rb:5:in `change'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.deleted_at does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS ...
                                            ^
: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL
C:/projectName/db/migrate/20161205141923_add_last_seen_at_to_users.rb:5:in `change'
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.deleted_at does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS ...
                                            ^
C:/projectName/db/migrate/20161205141923_add_last_seen_at_to_users.rb:5:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

As I say, I'm new to RoR, so I'm not really sure of what's wrong, going on, or - *evidently* - how to fix it.

I've tried Googling it, but all I can find is to `rake db:drop/create/migrate`, which does nothing to help.

Anyone want a crack at what's up?

Thanks,

Comment: What does `rake db:migrate:status` return?

Comment: @JoshBrody I'm reluctant to paste the results as it's not my project, but it's a table of around 60 up/down status', migration ID's, and migration names. What is this if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: as given on console output, 

```Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

        bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

):```

Comment: @marmeladze As I stated in my question, I've tried this, but nothing further happened

Comment: @RichardKeMiKaLGeNeRaLDenton It's merely a list of the migrations and their status. There's really no harm in posting them. We're looking for one that says "down" and not "up"; try `rake db:migrate:status | grep "up"`

Comment: @JoshBrody - There are about 20 of them with the status of UP and 40 with DOWN

Comment: What does running `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development` output? You posted the equivalent of `rails s` above.

Comment: @JoshBrody - It was quite long, so I edited my question including the results

Answer (score 1):

According to your migration errors, in the `20161205141923_add_last_seen_at_to_users.rb` migration found in `db/migrations`, you need to add `add_column :users, :deleted_at, :datetime` right beneath `def change` or `def up` (depending on your Rails version)

This column is probably also created in a later migration so you'll want to see where/if it breaks after you add this line.

Comment: Ah, ok, so now I might be getting somewhere! I tried adding the line as you've specified and now it seems to like it and has gone on to another error (and also tells me that this line already exists elsewhere). Before I start chasing all of these individually (there are a lot), I will speak to one of the devs from the company and see if they have come across this previously. Thanks for your help so far Josh, it's very much appreciated, and I may be back tomorrow!

Comment: The only thing I don't get is that they have this working?! Ooooooh, spooky puzzle!!!

Comment: you may be able to bypass this all together by doing a `rake db:schema:load; rake db:seed` — it'll load everything from `schema.rb` and won't run your migrations, but it sounds like there's some stuff missing.

Comment: JOSH... IT WORKS! Admittedly with errors, but running your `load` and `seed` made it burst into life! Thanks very much :)

Comment: @RichardKeMiKaLGeNeRaLDenton Probably what happened here is that the developers have - at some point - broken running migrations from scratch. This is not super uncommon. For example, it can often happen if an old migration references some data/method/database extension that no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your migrations, so that the timestamp in `schema.rb` is equal to the timestamp of last migration.

Run the command `rake db:migrate` if the database is setup.

Otherwise,

`rake db:create  #Create Database
 rake db:migrate #Run all migrations
 rake db:seed    #Load data from seeds.rb file`

Run `bundle install` before setting up database and executing migrations to install all the gems required to run the project.

Comment: I had previously tried `db:drop/create/migrate`, but hadn't come across `seed`, tried it, but it gives me the same output as running `rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`, as shown in my question

Comment: I think you need to setup your gems. I have a feeling that Paranoia gem is being used for setting up `deleted_at` field in `User` model.

After setting up gems by `bundle install` and following instructions of the gem through which `deleted_at` is being added, try running migrations again.